# Query a certain number of objects django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am creating a website that allows user to follow certain stocks and view articles related to what they follow. In 'index.html' I would only like to show the last 5 `Article`s for each `Stock` the user follows.

How can this be accomplished?

models.py:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        ticker = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed_stocks = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, blank=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()

class Article(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = 0 )
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    url = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    stocks_user_follows = list(request.user.profile.followed_stocks.all())
    articles_to_display = Article.objects.filter(stock__in = stocks_user_follows)

    return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'stocks_user_follows':stocks_user_follows, 'articles_to_display':articles_to_display})
```

index.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for stock in stocks_user_follows %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <h2>{{ stock }}</h2>
                    <ul>
                        {% for article in articles_to_display %}
                            {% if article.stock == stock %}
                                <li><a  href="{{article.url}}">{{ article.title }}</a></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-light w-50 mx-auto mb-4">All {{ stock }} News</a>

                </div>
            </div>
```

forms.py:

```
class StockFollowForm(forms.Form):
    stocks = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required =False,
                                           widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                           queryset=Stock.objects.all(),
                                           label= "",
                                           )
```

Comment: Stop posting duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2):

I can't identify by which criteria you would termine which articles are the 'last' or 'first', but you would only have to change one line of your code:

```
def index(request):
    ...
    articles_to_display = Article.objects.filter(stock__in = stocks_user_follows)[:5]
    ...
```

[Slice the quesrysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) to limit it to max 5 instances.

But you should consider adding an `order_by` call to the queryset so you get consistent results (the same 5 elements each time). You just have to define by which field you want to sort the data.